# Docker failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: No stored credential for https://index.docker.io/v1/

Tags: docker, macos, dockerfile

We try to run `docker build .. Dockerfile` under Mac OS `10.15.7` and encounter the error

`failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: No stored credential for https://index.docker.io/v1/`

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.16.3-alpine AS builder

# other commands
```

The docker version is `20.10.7`

What we have tried

- run `docker login xxxx`
- add `https://index.docker.io/v1/: {}` to `auths` of file `~/.docker/config.json`

Neither of them worked well.

How could we solve this error?

Comment: I've had a similar issue and fixed it by signing in in the Docker for Mac app and additionally running `docker login` command. However, now I'm stuck with `No stored credential for docker.elastic.co`...

Comment: @Najki  We solve it by manually running `docker pull ` the specific docker image.  It is so weird.

Comment: Wow @zangw, you're right! It actually worked. I wouldn't guess that workaround.

Comment: @Najki, one lastest method I did not do yet is re-install docker again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one workaround for this issue.

Just run `docker pull` the specific docker image manually.

Comment: Not really a real solution but I have to say it works :D

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for the same issue.
https://forums.docker.com/t/error-failed-to-solve-error-getting-credentials-err-exit-status-1-out/136124/6

"MacOS - I just had to change the docker config file.
The “credsStore” was “desktop” and changed it to “osxkeychain”.
used `nano` to do it. `sudo nano ~/.docker/config.json`"